# Create cron task in Odoo13

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

I am working on a new module in Odoo13CE and trying to create a scheduled task with the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <record forcecreate="True" id="electricity_charges_cron" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">Get electricity charges</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="electricity_charges.model_electricity_charges_readings"/>
            <field name="active" eval="True" />
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">model.set_readings()</field>
            <field name="interval_number">6</field>
            <field name="interval_type">hours</field>
            <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
            <field name="active" eval="False" />
            <field name="doall" eval="True" />
            <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root" />
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

But when install or update the module this error appears:

```
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "null value in column "activity_user_type" violates not-null constraint
```

Any idea how I can resolve this error? Have the mail module installed.

Comment: The field is defined in the `mail` module. Does your module depend on the `mail` module?

Comment: Hi Kenly! My module doesn't depend on the mail module. It is a module that does not depend on any other. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't mail installed next to base?

Comment: Is installed next to base but not configured because doesn't needed.

Comment: Solved! Updated the mail modules and uninstall ans reinstall my module.